# Live Ubuntu boot from a CD/USB drive

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I was wondering, If I boot by laptop, a Windows-7 x64, (present at my work place and which is connected to my work network which has internet connection) from a Live Ubuntu CD or a Live USB drive, then get into the Ubuntu OS -

1. Would I be able to connect to internet from that laptop, using the Live CD boot on my laptop, and browse the web. Any configuration/setting changes that I need to do once I boot into Live Ubuntu, to achieve this?
2. If I have booted into this Live CD Ubuntu/Live USB ubuntu, would I be able to install packages using  - apt-get install  ?
3. If I install Ubuntu on my windows laptop using [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer), would I be able to do 1 and 2 above from Ubuntu which is installed using Wubi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a LiveCD maker like Unetbootin, you can reserve part of the space on a thumbdrive to allow changes to be made. This will allow you to install programs and different things and them show up again the next time you boot.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your wireless card is a supported card, you can easily connect to Internet with Live CD/USB.
2. You can install some packages but if you restart your computer your changes will deleted.
3. WUBI likes a full installation. You can install WUBI and use everything on Ubuntu.

Comment: When you say 'can install some packages', are there any limitations, that all/any packages cannot be installed? And about WUBI, so it's like a normal Ubuntu where in can install anything package on that Ubuntu and access it next time even after reset? Correct?

Comment: @goldenmean: almost anything will work. Exceptions are some driver packages - like wifi and graphic cards, because they usually require restart to load (not necessary, you can dynamically load them, but it's complicated).

Comment: @goldenmean: in live cd, i guess your limitation is your ram. In WUBI, Ubuntu will be installed on your hard disk and you can use every future of Ubuntu. Restart doesn't broke anything. The difference between normal Ubuntu installation and WUBI, WUBI installation starts from Windows and easier than normal installation. Wubi has some performance disadvantage but new user can easily use it.